# looking for a good Linux tool for hindi transcription

Tags: linux, software-rec, i18n

I'm looking for a Hindi transcription tool in Linux. For English, VOSK is pretty good since it recognizes both Indian and US English. Is there anything that any agency (like C-DAC) under the Govt. of India has developed? Please help me.

Comment: your question belongs at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/